# What is the purpose, and proper use of wantTo() in Codeception?

Tags: codeception

I'm using the testing framework Codeception to do BDD. I understand the idea of wanting something, but I don't understand what the function does.

```
$I->wantTo('Understand what this method does!');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Comments

> Commands like amGoingTo, expect, expectTo help you in making tests
> more descriptive.

```
$I->wantTo('Understand what this method does!');
```

will be rendered as `* I want to understand what this method does!` in verbose output.

**Update 2022-11-16**:

My original answer was incorrect, `wantTo` is not a comment method, it renames test method in the output.

Example:

I created very simple Cest class:

```
<?php

class ExampleCest
{
    public function provideExample(CliGuy $I)
    {
    }
}
```

When I ran it, I got the following output:

```
Cli Tests (1) --------------------------------------------
U ExampleCest: Provide example (0.00s)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

but after adding `$I->wantTo('change test name!');` to method:
I got the following output:

```
Cli Tests (1) --------------------------------------------
U ExampleCest: Change test name! (0.00s)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The benefit of `wantTo` is that it allows to use characters not permitted in method names or different formatting than automatically generated.

I looked up if `wantTo` has any documentation and all I found was old blog post using examples in class-less Cept format (which is deprecated and is likely to be removed in Codeception 6).

```php
<?php

$I = new TestGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('log in to site');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('Login');
$I->fillField('username', 'admin');
```

In Cept format `wantTo` had better purpose, because it didn't override anything, but provided additional information next to file name.

Comment: Strangely, that page or any other doesn't seem to even list `wantTo()`.

Comment: My answer was incorrect, I updated it.

Comment: Oh! That's pretty curious and useful. Thanks for updating it!